# variadic template value as template argument for struct

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

I try to do something like this :

```
template <int v1, template <typename... Args> Args... vx> struct Sum {
   const static int RESULT = v1 + Sum<vx...>::RESULT;
};

template <int v> struct Sum {
   const static int RESULT = v;
}
```

To use like this :

```
int a = Sum<1, 2>::RESULT;
int b = Sum<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>::RESULT;
```

Obviously, something is wrong here and I'm struggling with the concept of variadic template as value in a struct/class definition. Is it possible to do something like this? How?

Thanks...

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark the answer which resolved your problem as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems is that neither template declaration specializes the other *and* the code in these declaration differs, so the code is ill-formed.

Also you aren't actually using the template as a template parameter here, and it's not needed for the code, as you can see here:

```
// main template
template <int v1, int... vx> struct Sum {
    const static int RESULT = v1 + Sum<vx...>::RESULT;
};

// specialization to make recursion terminate
// the list of matched template parameters is listed
// after the name of the struct in angle brackets
template <int v> struct Sum<v> {
    const static int RESULT = v;
};

static_assert(Sum<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>::RESULT == 15, "");

int main() {}
```

Comment: milleniumbug, many thanks! I tried something like this but it didn't work (I think that I forget the <v> in the specialized version of the Sum). This is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks again!

Comment: @jcdemers You're welcome. As a way of expressing gratitude, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer to your question if it helped you resolve the problem.